# Filter IEnumerable using 3 dropdowns

Tags: c#, asp.net, ienumerable

I have a list of ID's which I need to filter depending on the values selected in 3 dropdown boxes. I got it working for 2 dropdowns, but can see that this is not the best way to complete it:

```
var nodesList = new List<int>();

                // Check each item in search output against the values in the dropdown boxes
                bool found = false;

                foreach (var item in searchOutput) // searchOut is an IEnumerable
                {
                    // This is where I need to add another dropdown box option but realise the code below is going to get even messier !!

                    if (GetNodeProperty(item.Id, "sportChooser", "sportChooser").Contains(ddlSport.SelectedValue))
                    {
                        if (ddlCategory.SelectedIndex == 0 || GetNodeProperty(item.Id, "categoryChooser", "categoryChooser").Contains(ddlCategory.SelectedValue))
                        {
                            found = true;
                        }
                    }

                    if (GetNodeProperty(item.Id, "categoryChooser", "categoryChooser").Contains(ddlCategory.SelectedValue))
                    {
                        if (ddlSport.SelectedIndex == 0 || GetNodeProperty(item.Id, "sportChooser", "sportChooser").Contains(ddlSport.SelectedValue))
                        {
                            found = true;
                        }
                    }

                    if (found)
                    {
                        nodesList.Add(item.Id);
                        found = false;
                    }

                }

                lvSearchResult.DataSource = nodesList;
                lvSearchResult.DataBind();
            }
```

I'm presuming some form of Lambda expression would be more suitable, but for the life of me cannot seem to get it working. This is what I have so far:

```
foreach (var item in searchOutput)
                {
                    nodesList.Add(item.Id);
                }
                List<int> filteredNodes = nodesList
                    .Where(
                        x =>
                        GetNodeProperty(Convert.ToInt32(x.ToString()), "categoryChooser", "categoryChooser").Contains(ddlCategory.SelectedValue))
                    .Where(
                        x =>
                        GetNodeProperty(Convert.ToInt32(x.ToString()), "sportChooser", "sportChooser").Contains(ddlSport.SelectedValue))
                    .ToList();
```

Note: I need to filter searchOutput by a combination of the 3 dropdowns whether something has been selected or not.

Answer (score 0):

Grrr, why is it you solve these things after going public !!

```
// Check each item in search output against the values in the dropdown boxes
            foreach (var item in searchOutput)
            {
                nodesList.Add(item.Id);
            }

            List<int> filteredNodes = nodesList
                .Where(
                    x =>
                    ((ddlCategory.SelectedIndex == 0 || GetNodeProperty(Convert.ToInt32(x.ToString()), "categoryChooser", "categoryChooser").Contains(ddlCategory.SelectedValue)) && (ddlSport.SelectedIndex == 0 || GetNodeProperty(Convert.ToInt32(x.ToString()), "sportChooser", "sportChooser").Contains(ddlSport.SelectedValue))) && (ddlFileType.SelectedIndex == 0 || ContentType(Convert.ToInt32(x.ToString())) == ddlFileType.SelectedValue.ToLower()))
                .ToList();

            lvSearchResult.DataSource = filteredNodes;
            lvSearchResult.DataBind();
```